# Trying to install FatJar in Eclipse Error

Tags: java, eclipse, plugins

So I was trying to install FatJar plugin, and for some reason, I get this error, can anyone help(I do have the newest Eclipse, and I'm on a mac)?

[image]

I am installing the plugin using **Help > Installing new software**, and the link is http://kurucz-grafika.de/fatjar.